# Standard method of showing that two $\sigma$-algebras coincide

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have $\sigma$-algebras $A,B$ and $C$. The task is to show that $A$ coincide with the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(B\cup C)$ generated by $B \cup C$. I left out the properties of $A,B,C$ deliberately, because I want to know if there exist a standard method of showing this, assuming the statement is true. For me, the natural way would be to start with an element in $A$ and show that it lies in $\sigma(B\cup C)$, and vice versa. I'm struggling with how to work with the implicit definition of a generated $\sigma$-algebra, hence I am not sure how to proceed. I'm sure that there is an easy way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Usually one inclusion will be obvious: for example, if $B$ and $C$ are contained in $A$, then so is $\sigma(B\cup C)$. For the other inclusion, perhaps $A$ is defined to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by something else, and one has to check that this something else is contained in $\sigma (A\cup B)$?

Comment: Alright, so if I can show that $A$ is generated by say a collection of sets and that this collection is contained in $\sigma(B\cup C)$, it would be done? I have been stuck on trying to figure out how to explicitly characterize elements in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [monotone class theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem). Another, more advanced, method is to explicitely construct all sets in the generated $\sigma$-algebra by transfinite induction.

If you are lucky, you can simply show that $B\cup C\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq\sigma(B\cup C)$ diectly, from which the desired result wouuld follow easily.

Comment: Thank both of you for answering. In this case, I'm pretty sure that it can be shown that each $\sigma$-algebra is contained in the other one. As @Etienne pointed out, one direction is easy, but then again, I'm not sure how to show that an element in $A$ lies in $\sigma(B\cup C)$ due to its implicit definition.